# How does regularization affect the offset term and weights for OLS?

Tags: regression, least-squares, lasso, regularization, tikhonov-regularization

I have a couple of questions regarding regularization that I am confused on, and searches on this forum doesn't seem to answer my specific questions.

When we regularize with $\lambda ||w||^2$ or $\lambda |w|$, the offset term in the linear model isn't regularized.

However, it seems that applying regularization still changes the offset, which I think makes sense even though we're not regularizing the offset, specifically. My question is, is there any theoretical or empirical knowledge on whether the offset tends to increase or decrease when using regularization?

My second question is regarding the weights, $w$. When we regularize, we are limiting the size of the weights, and they tend to decrease. However, if this was multiple regression, and $w$ is a vector instead of a scalar, then there is no guarantee that all components of the weight vector decreases correct, and only that $\ell_2$ or $\ell_1$ norm of the weights vector decreases? So, we could actually see a component of the weights vector increase under regularization even if the norm of the vector decreases?

Comment: Have you examined our [threads on ridge regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22ridge%20regression%22)  Many of them provide formulas and intuitive explanations for how the parameter estimates vary with $\lambda.$  For discussions of the $l_1$ situation look at posts on the Lasso.

Comment: @whuber I looked at several of the threads before, but I don't recall a discussion on how the offset term responds to regularization.